# 'gethostbyname' isn't working correctly

Tags: php

**EDIT:** This issue has been fixed. The issue was that the 'gethostbyname' was picking up the new lines from the file. Thank you [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver) for pointing that out.

I have a CSV list of data which I am converting into an array, the CSV data has two columns, an account and a domain name. It is my job to go through all of the domain names, convert them into IPs, and determine whether we own the IP address or not. But the problem is that the 'gethostbyname' function is only working for the last item in the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

    // Error reporting
    ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    // Load the CSV file
    $rawInput = file("data.csv");

    // Format the data
    $newData = array();

    foreach ($rawInput as $entry) {
        $exData = explode(",", $entry);
        array_push($newData, array(
            "account" => $exData[0],
            "address" => $exData[1]
        ));
    }


    // Let the magic begin...
    $finalOutput = "";

    foreach ($newData as $dataEntry) {

        // Check if we own the IP
        $ipAdrr = gethostbyname("www.".$dataEntry["address"]."."); // It doesn't work without the trailing '.' too
        $exData = explode(".", $ipAdrr);

        var_dump($exData); echo("<br>");

        /*if (intval($exData[0]) == 188 && intval($exData[0]) == 64) {

        }*/
    }

    // Finalise table
    $finalOutput = $finalOutput."\t\t\t</table>\n";

?>
```

And the CSV file looks like this.

```
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
example,example.com
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you very much!

Comment: please include your CSV (or at least an excerp)

Comment: if you echo in the for loop are the values correct then?  is $dataEntry["address"] changing in value each time?  If they are then the problem is in gethostbyname, and we'd need that code.

Comment: I'm unable to do so since it's private company material, however I assure you they all follow the example format. But the TLDs do vary (most of them being .co.uk), and some are on subdomains.

Comment: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` or `trim`.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus 'gethostbyname' is a default PHP function.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The file is loading correctly into the array.

Comment: Yes, but all except the last line have a newline and then you are concatenating a `.` My comment was not a suggestion, it was the answer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah apologies, that seems to have fixed it. Forgot all about those hidden new lines. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RowlandShaw Was just about to ask that myself, I've updated the original post too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file()` is keeping the newlines which will not work in the `gethostbyname()` call.  Also, you are adding a `.` to the end so except for the last entry you have:

`www.example.com
.`

Use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` in the `file()` call or use `trim()` on the string before using it.